# sum and difference of four cubes times sum and difference of four cubes equals sum and difference of four cubes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The original proof of the four square theorem relied on Euler's great identity that the sum of four squares times the sum of four squares equals the sum of four squares. Currently it is an open problem whether every integer can be written as the sum and difference of four cubes. If it turned out to be that there existed an identity that proved that the sum and difference of four cubes times sum and difference of four cubes equals sum and difference of four cubes, then it would simplify the open problem to determining if the problem is true for primes (and thus would be true for all integers by the FTA). Does such an identity exist?
Btw we know that this problem is true for all integers not of the form 4 or 5 mod 9, so the existence of such an identity would actually reduce the problem to just primes of the form 4 or 5 mod 9.

Comment: I don't think it is known that numbers not congruent to $4$ or $5$ modulo $9$ can be written as a sum of four cubes (i.e. that one can restrict to numbers congruent to $4$ or $5$ modulo $9$ when proving the conjecture). Also, I don't think it is known that if every (sufficiently large) prime number is a sum of four cubes, then every (sufficiently large) natural number is a sum of four cubes. Finally, I believe it is known (and not hard to prove) that there is no Euler-type identity for a sum of four cubes.

Comment: As far as your first comment is concerned, read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_four_cubes_problem. Demjanenko proved it.

Comment: I had a sum of four (nonnegative) cubes in mind. Sorry for the confusion.